# How to make video fill frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

The video in my home page div does not fill the div immediately, you have to refresh the page for that to happen. Otherwise there is black left and right.

This happens in Firefox & Chrome on my PC but not on my Mac.

I have been working on this for some days and if anyone could help I wold appreciate it!

My site is here http://www.vanhove.net/wateredgerealty/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline style on the video tag, it changes the height wich will also change the witdh and therefore create black bars.

```
<video style="width: 100%;"></video>
```

Comment: OK I changed 

<video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">

to

<video autoplay loop style="width: 100%;">

but that did not help.

Btw I got this approach froim http://jsfiddle.net/mgmilcher/8R7Xx/sho/